Azure AD B2C authentication in an ASP.NET Core application
I want to implement authentication using azure ad b2c. I have covered all the prior requirements such as an azure b2c tenant account (directory) and have an idea of registering application.
My main requirement is to just have sign in policy and no sign up policy. To do so I need to create users, right? (to provide login creds to users with password reset on first sign in). I have an idea that it could be done through graph but please provide some information for it as well.
Please provide any prior implementation reference of the above requirement if you have.

If you are using user flows, you just select "User flow / Create a user flow" and then select from the various flows, e.g. sign in / signup, etc.
You can create test users in the portal as well and specify a password for them.
There is no automatic password reset on the first sign-in.
If you want to do that, use custom policies.
There is an ASP.NET sample here.
